# Need help deploying my first web application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js, dll

first of all, sorry if I'm difficult to understand, english isn't my mother language but I'll try to explain.

I was asked to migrate a desktop application to the cloud to provide it as SaaS so I thought AWS was my best option. This application has a Vue frontend and the core of the application is a dll. Now I'm stuck not knowing how to procceed and I will thank if somebody could give me some clues.

Comment: Sadly recommendation questions are off topic. But look maybe at AWS ElasticBeanstalk.

Comment: Hi, SO is not a place for a "how-to" tutorial. Meanwhile, the simplest solution is to split your things. Host your frontend on Netlify/Vercel and your backend on something like Heroku (with a simple platform who can do the biggest work for you).

Comment: Potential starting points [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/guides/deploy-webapp-decision/) or [here](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/language/net/solutions/) if it's .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to provision a Windows EC2 instance to run the DLL, as DLL is a Windows specific concept. As for the Vue, when you say desktop application, I assume you mean either Electron or browser based, in which case if it's web, you would need to deploy the web application via EC2 or Elastic Beanstalk, and point its backend to the Windows EC2 running the DLL.